# Retain start and end IDs when creating spatial lines from X Y points

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, spatial

The following code will create SpatialLines that connect all x/y points in a dataset.  However, each of those x/y points has a unique ID.  I need to retain both the startpoint and the endpoint IDs of the x/y as "attributes" (the ArcGIS term) of each of the SpatialLines that connect them.

Help would be appreciated.

## I have a dataset of XY values that looks like this

```
x<-c(2,4,6,3,7,9,1)
y<-c(6,4,8,2,9,6,1)
id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
dataset<-data.frame(cbind(x,y,id))
dataset$x<-as.numeric(as.character(dataset$x)) #converting from factor to numeric
dataset$y<-as.numeric(as.character(dataset$y))

plot(dataset$x,dataset$y)
```

## Replicate the dataframe to cover for all possible combinations

```
dataset<-do.call(rbind, replicate(7, dataset, simplify=FALSE))
```

## Now, create a matrix with all the same destination points, mixed:

```
nm=matrix(ncol=3)
for (i in 1:7){
  nm<-rbind(nm,do.call(rbind,replicate(7,as.matrix(dataset[i,]),simplify=FALSE)))
}
nm<-nm[-1,]
```

## Rename the columns of matrix, so they make sense, and bind the existing data frame with the new matrix

```
colnames(nm)<-c("x2","y2","id.dest")
newds<-cbind(dataset,as.data.frame(nm))
```

## Remove duplicated trajectories:

```
newds1<-newds[-which(newds$id==newds$id.dest),]
```

## converting destination x & y to numeric from factor

```
newds1$x2<-as.numeric(as.character(newds1$x2)) #converting from factor to numeric
newds1$y2<-as.numeric(as.character(newds1$y2))
```

## plotting the destination points . . .same as the origin points

```
plot(newds1$x, newds1$y) 
plot(newds1$x2, newds1$y2, col="red")
```

####*

## converting the begin and end points to spatial lines

### raw list to store Lines objects

```
l <- vector("list", nrow(newds1)) #
```

## this l is now an empty vector w/ number of rows defined by length (nrow) of newds1

## splitting origin and destination coordinates so I can run this script

```
 origins<-data.frame(cbind(newds1$x, newds1$y))
    destinations<-data.frame(cbind(newds1$x2, newds1$y2))

    library(sp)
    for (i in seq_along(l)) {
      l[[i]] <- Lines(list(Line(rbind(origins[i, ], destinations[i,]))), as.character(i))
    }

    l.spatial<-SpatialLines(l)
    plot(l.spatial, add=T)
```

The object newds1 contains both the startpoint and endpoint.  However, the final SpatialLines that are created from those start and endpoints (l.spatial) do not contain a reference to the start and endpoints.  I would like those SpatialLines to contain two "attribute" columns that refer to the IDs of the start and endpoints. I think this is a matter of binding newds1 (a dataframe) onto l.spatial (spatial lines), but the code I'm running doesn't seem to do it.

## Attempting to spatially bind the start and end IDs to l.spatial

```
row.names(newds1)<-1:length(newds1$id) #renaming rows in the dataframe so they match the spatial object

id<-newds1$id
newds2<-spCbind(l.spatial, id)
```

I get

```
"Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spCbind’ for signature ‘"SpatialLines", "factor"’"
```

Comment: You can't, without keeping your own index into the geometry.Maybe use the trip package? Happy to discuss options

Comment: Now I see what you are doing, I'll answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

```
newds2 <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(l.spatial, newds1, match.ID = FALSE)  
## or you can use the rownames of newds1 in the lines loop)
```

There are 42 distinct lines, made by matching every coordinate to each other coordinate once.

FWIW, you don't need to convert from factor for numeric:

```
 x <- c(2,4,6,3,7,9,1)
 y <- c(6,4,8,2,9,6,1)
 id <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
 ## don't coerce to character in the 
 ##first place cbind(x, y, id) *must* be 
 ## character and then data.frame 
 ## converts characters to factors 
 dataset <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, id = id)
```

There are other ways to simplify your task, but here's a reasonably straightforward way (I think this is what you are after):

x <- c(2,4,6,3,7,9,1)
   y <- c(6,4,8,2,9,6,1)
   id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
   ## don't coerce to character in the first place cbind(x, y, id) *must* be character
    ## and then data.frame converts characters to factors by default
    dataset<-data.frame(x = x, y = y, id = id)

```
l <- vector("list", nrow(dataset) * (nrow(dataset) - 1)) 
origID <- destID <- character(length(l))
##xy <- as.matrix(dataset[, c("x", "y")])
cnt <- 0
for (i in seq(nrow(dataset))) {
  pt0 <- as.matrix(dataset[i, c("x", "y") ])
  pts <- dataset[-i, ]
  for (j in seq(nrow(pts))) {
    cnt <- cnt + 1
    l[[cnt]] <- Lines(list(Line(rbind(pt0, as.matrix(pts[j, c("x", "y")])))), as.character(cnt))
    destID[cnt] <- pts$id[j]
    origID[cnt] <- dataset$id[i]
  }
}

x <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(SpatialLines(l), data.frame(dest = destID, orig = origID, row.names = as.character(1:cnt)))
```

Pick out one line and investigate:

```
itest <- 10
## so for example
as.data.frame(x[itest, ])

index <- c(x$orig[itest], x$dest[itest])
plot(x)
plot(x[itest, ], lwd = 4, add = TRUE)
lines(dataset[index, c("x", "y")], col = "firebrick", lwd = 2)
text(dataset[index, c("x", "y")], label = dataset$id[index], col = "dodgerblue", cex = 4)
```